# Error in netbeans UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java

I'm working in a project that deals with apache library, but I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

in my netbeans config :

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Should I change the JDK version, or is the error has other solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12850336/1531971 (But, yes. There is a compiled vs. runtime Java version skew in your project.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error corresponds to your JDK, with the number telling you what  version it is looking for, in your case it looks like it requires JDK 8 and you are currently running JDK 7.